# Displaying absolute div below floating element

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website — a portfolio of my work. On the main page, I have a grid of images; each image is a link to the page for that project.

My issue now is the mouse-hover description text. I want a short description to appear below the image when the user hovers over it.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6crL7df7/

The issue I am having is how I can get the description to appear *directly* beneath the image. In the prototype, I have manually set `bottom: -50px;`, but this needs to be adjusted for different amounts of text. I would like the **top** of the div to automatically align with the **bottom** of its image. I saw some answers saying that `bottom: 0;` would work, but it didn't for me.

The image itself is `float: left;` while the description is `position: absolute;`; the div that contains them both is both `float: left;` and `position: relative;`.

I will gladly take any suggestions to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spec from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-bottom):

> `bottom` specifies how far a box's bottom margin edge is offset above
>   the bottom of the box's containing block.
>
> `top` property specifies how far an absolutely positioned box's top margin
>   edge is offset below the top edge of the box's containing block.

Instead of `bottom`, use `top` property with a value equal or bigger than `100%`.

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6crL7df7/1/)**

```css
div.description {
    /* other declarations... */
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%; /* Anything >= 100% */
}
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe I should have read the spec... That was easy. `top: 100%` Does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the following adjustment to your CSS rule:

```
div.description {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: small;

    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; /* set top to be bottom edge of parent block */
    margin-top: -5px; /* adjust as needed */
    z-index: 1;

    visibility: hidden;

}
```

Specity the `top` offset to position the description block below the bottom edge of the
parent block, and then use `margin-top` to control the white space (use a negative margin
is so needed).

Note that this is essentially the same as an earlier posted solution.